# Writing out to CSV Error

Tags: bash, csv, terminal

I have inherited a script from a coworker who has left the company and was, shall we say, lazy when it came to writing scripts and keeping notes. Before he left he insisted that this script was working perfectly, but would never make a time to show it to me or verify that it would work in a new environment and now I'm stuck with it.

It seems to be working ok except for the fact that it is not writing out to CSV as it is supposed to. It should give me file names of images, width, height, and the total pixel count. What I am getting is file name, blank, blank, variablenamevariablename. Any help would be appreciated:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# This script will display 
# all images included

ORIGDIR=~/Desktop/EPUB_Fix/Needs_Work
DIRECTORY=~/Desktop/EPUB_Fix/Work_Area
DESTINATION=~/Desktop/EPUB_Fix/Fixed
PROCESSED=~/Desktop/EPUB_Fix/Original_Files
EPUB=*.epub

cd ~/Desktop

cp -v $ORIGDIR/$EPUB $DIRECTORY
mv -v  $ORIGDIR/$EPUB $PROCESSED

#cd $PROCESSED
#rename 's@(.*?)\.epub@$1_orig.epub@' $EPUB

cd $DIRECTORY

for epubfile in $(ls "$DIRECTORY"/$EPUB); do
    echo 
    echo =================================
    echo 
    zipfile=$(basename $epubfile .epub).zip
    directoryname=$(basename $zipfile .zip)
    mv -v "$epubfile" "$DIRECTORY"/"$zipfile"
    ziperror=0
    ziperror=$(unzip -t "$DIRECTORY"/"$zipfile" > /dev/null)$?

    if [ $ziperror -eq "0" ]; then
        unzip -o "$DIRECTORY"/"$zipfile" -d "$DIRECTORY"/"$directoryname"

        echo
        echo "Printing file name to CSV"
        for eisbn in $(find $DIRECTORY/$directoryname); do
            EVALUE=0
            while [ $EVALUE -eq 0 ]; do
                eisbn=$(basename $directoryname)
                echo "EISBN: $eisbn" > $eisbn.csv
                let EVALUE=1
            done
        done
        echo "Printing image names"
        echo >> $eisbn.csv
        echo Name,Width,Height,Total >> $eisbn.csv
        echo >> $eisbn.csv
    echo "Printing total images with their sizes"
        echo
        for image in $(find $DIRECTORY/$directoryname -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.jpeg" -o -name "*.png" -o -name "*.gif"); do
            size="$(identify --format "%w %h" "$image")"
            width="${size%% *}"
            height="${size##* }" 
            imagename=$(basename $image)
            total=$(($width * $height))
            echo $imagename,$width,$height,$total >> $eisbn.csv
        done

        for dbfile in $(find $DIRECTORY/$directoryname -name Thumbs.db); do
            rm -v $dbfile
        done

        for dsfile in $(find $DIRECTORY/$directoryname -name .DS_Store); do
            rm -v $dsfile
        done

        for plistfile in $(find $DIRECTORY/$directoryname -name iTunesMetadata.plist); do
            rm -v $plistfile
        done

        for ologfile in $(find $DIRECTORY/$directoryname -name Output.log); do
            rm -v $ologfile
        done

        for csvfile in $(find $DIRECTORY -name *.csv); do
            mv -v $csvfile $LOG
        done        

        cd "$DIRECTORY"/"$directoryname"
        cp -v -f /media/sf_epubs/mimetype "$DIRECTORY"/"$directoryname"
        zip -X -0 $DESTINATION/$directoryname.zip mimetype
        zip -r $DESTINATION/$directoryname.zip * -x mimetype
        mv -v $DESTINATION/$directoryname.zip $DESTINATION/$directoryname.epub
        rm -v -r "$DIRECTORY"/"$directoryname"
        rm -v "$DIRECTORY"/$zipfile
    fi
done
```

Comment: If you choose an image file and run `identify --format "%w %h" <imagefile.jpg>`, what is the output?

Comment: This is a bash script, so don't invoke it like `sh scriptname`

Answer (score 0):

At the line `size="$(identify --format "%w %h" "$image")"` format option should be `-format` not `--format`

Try changing that line to and see if it helps

> size="$(identify -format '%w %h' $image)"